# Сколько раз функция может вызвать саму себя? C/C++

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Сколько раз функция может вызвать саму себя и от чего это зависит

Comment: пока есть место в стеке и от размера стека и от самой функции(кол-во аргументов например), если Вы про рекурсию

Comment: Если применяется оптимизация хвостового вызова - то сколько угодно.

Comment: @VTT не слышал такого термина, но понял что речь про оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии. Вероятно потому что не пишу на плюсах, там это так называют?

Comment: Ну это дословно TCO `tail call optimization`. Этот вид оптимизации не обязательно подразумевает рекурсивный вызов.

Comment: @VTT, "хвостовая рекурсия" - это как-то уж слишком странно звучит. Не стоит переводить так уж дословно, "tail" - это же не только "хвост". Наверное, лучше будет "заключительная рекурсия" или что-нибудь в этом роде.

Comment: Зависит от максимального размера стека и объёма локальных переменных в функции. Если например в функции локальный массив `long double arr[1000000];` - то очень мало останется глубины стека.

Comment: @freim, а вы попробуйте загуглить "хвостовая рекурсия" и "заключительная рекурсия")

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, зачем это гуглить? Я знаю, что "хвостовая рекурсия" употребляется, но это не делает термин удачным. Просто бездумный дословный перевод, который, к сожалению, вошел в употребление.

Comment: @freim, если вы и дальше будете придумывать "более удачные" термины, то кончится тем что вас просто перестанут понимать окружающие

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, до сих пор как-то понимали, но я, несомненно, учту ваше предупреждение.

Comment: @freim термин   крутится в среде десятилетиями https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сколько угодно - но пока ей позволяет память.

Каждый вызов требует *в общем случае* место в стеке для хранения адреса возврата и локальных переменных (включая переданные аргументы).

Естественно, всякие частные случаи и оптимизации могут влиять на указанное количество необходимой для одного вызова памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря какая функция. Вы можете регулировать количество вызовов ставя условие (или утверждение) или генерировав исключение. Например такая функция:

```
void foo() {
    static int k = 1;
    if (k++ > 2) return;
    cout << k <<' ';
    foo();   
}
```

Может вызвать саму себя всего один раз...